# IIS PHP include files stopped working unless I delete old & create new

Tags: php

Include files won't work on a Win 7 Pro machine unless I...

- Copy include file contents
- delete old include file
- paste and save contents in a new include file with same name

Switched to a Win 7 Pro machine I had with
IIS Version 6.1
and PHP Version 5.6.31

Example of a couple of dozen files that are included in the application:

```php
<?php
include "inc_header_public.php";
?>
```

This application was working on my former Win 10 machine running the same version of iis and php. That machine crashed and I moved to my backup machine running Win 7 Pro.
For some reason I have to replace each of the include files in order to make the darn thing work.
Old files give me this error..

> `PHP Warning:  include(C:\mySite\inc_header_public.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\mySite\inc_header.php on line 23`
>
> `PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'inc_header_public.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\mySite\inc_header.php on line 23`

Old & new include file  properties look the same.

Comment: Have you checked the Properties -> Security tab and the correct permission given to the user running IIS on your win 7?

Comment: the security properties for both the old and new security files seem to be the same via right clicking each file and clicking Properties > Security. All other PHP files seem to work OK. Problem just with old include files. I've spent several  hours on this so hopefully some kind soul can help me figure it out. Thanks.